# Xamarin OnImageClick in ListView change image color

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a ListView with a Grid within. In the Grid I have an image, but now I want to be able to click on the image and when I have done that, the image should change colors.
Here is my axml of my ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMain" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#212121" SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid x:Name="GridMain">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" x:Name="Row0_Height"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="180" x:Name="Row1_Height"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="180" x:Name="Row2_Height"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" x:Name="Row3_Height"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" x:Name="Column0_Width" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="Column1_Width" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" x:Name="Column2_Width" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Creator}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Body" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                            <Image Source="VoteUp.png" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Image Source="VoteDown.png" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageLocation}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
                            <Image Source="Favorite.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                            <Image Source="Send_Dark.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            <Image Source="Save_Dark.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Take for example the Save_Dark.png, how can I set a clicklistener on that image and then change the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a gesture recognizer

```
<Image Source="Save_Dark.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End" >
  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Image_Tapped" />
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

protected void Image_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  var i = (Image)sender;
  i.Source = ... new image source here ...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the color of the image? The image contains only one color

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  You would need to have two versions of the image and just swap them.